# Configuring wazuh rule to alert modsecurity events

Tags: mod-security, wazuh

I have a problem with creating rules with Wazuh, I want to  monitor mod security events in the Apache logs, and I want Wazuh to alert every time mod security blocks an attack.

There are predefined rules for that, and I included the log source, but I don't get alerted.

I tried to create a new rule that matches the pattern, but I get:

```
Mod Security: Access denied with code 403
```

I tried to attack a locally hosted web application, and the WAF blocked the attack, the logs were recorded in `/var/log/apache/error.log`.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Could you show your relevant log entries from `/var/log/apache/error.log`?